# Firebase Hosting - How to prevent access for some files

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have couple of html files in public folder at firebase hosting listed as below.
index.html
content_1.html
content_2.html
app.js
app.css

consider domain name is example.com

as of now user can access all these file using syntax example.com/content_1.html or  example.com/app.css.

is it possible to prevent direct access to these files but index.html ? I use these files while building the index.html through jquery

In Apache would have used  `Order allow,deny` and   `Allow from all` at httpd.conf, but not sure how to achieve this on Firebase Hosting.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to prevent direct access to these files but index.html ? I use these files while building the index.html through jquery

You cannot simultaneously provide indirect access to a resource required by a web page and block it from direct access at the client level regardless of the web server being used unless you're assembling things on the server first.