# Securing Firebase Hosting web site with a GCP VPN

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-vpn

I am working on a platform (*www.dashboard.example.com*) that has an admin site (*www.admin.example.com*). Each site is hosted on a different **Google Firebase Hosting Project**.

I want only certain people to be able to access the admin site. After some consideration, I found an **IPSec VPN** to be the best solution for me.

I also found that GCP offers a [VPN service](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/), but from what I can tell, it seems to only work with google compute engines.

#### Is there a way to attach a Google VPN to a Firebase Hosted site?

Comment: There is currently no way to secure (part of) a web site that is on Firebase Hosting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140014/firebase-hosting-how-to-prevent-access-for-some-files

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to attach a Cloud VPN to a Firebase Hosting Project.

In GCP the correct way to restrict the access to your web server/application is by using firewall rules/App Engine's firewall and Cloud VPC/VPN service.

Your approach should be to put a proxy by configuring a Google Compute Engine[1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations) in between your gateway service and your Firebase Hosting Project.

Another approach would be to use Cloud Storage[2](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#choosing_an_option), as a static website[3](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#static-site). You can then create an HTTPS Load Balancer based on Backend Bucket[4](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-bucket). With this you can benefit from the advantages of using Load Balancer and also using Cloud VPN.

If you are interested in authentication with Firebase and App Engine I suggest to check the following link [2](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#choosing_an_option).

---